# Объединение массивов со сложением значений ключей

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в сторону чего смотреть по след. задаче.

Имеется многомерный массив вида (существует возможность сгенерировать отдельные массивы, но их количество может быть разным - наверное, в многомерном удобнее будет обрабатывать):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 2
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
        [3] => -10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 3
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 4
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 1
        [3] => -11
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 10
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 3
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 7
    )

)
```

Требуется объединить массивы с идентичными ключами[0]. Т.е. объединить имена, при этом, чтобы значения всех иных ключей складывались.

На выходе должен получиться результат, по примеру:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 17
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name 2
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
        [3] => -10
    )
...
```

Попытка была исходить из решения: https://toster.ru/q/60856 - но тогда удаётся создать новый массив, без копий имён (т.е. ключ[0] объединяется), но ключи иные не удаётся объединить.

Каким методом убрать копии (соединить по ключу[0]), чтобы при этом ключи[1][2][3] от дублей объединились - затрудняюсь понять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$arr = array(
  array('Name 1', 1, 0, 7),
  array('Name 2', 1, 0, -10),
  array('Name 3', 0, 1, 6),
  array('Name 4', 0, 1, -11),
  array('Name 1', 1, 0, 10),
  array('Name 3', 0, 1, 7)
);

$result = array();
foreach($arr as $block) {
  if(array_key_exists($block[0], $result)) {
    for($j = 1; $j < 4; $j++) {
      $result[$block[0]][$j] += $block[$j];
    }
  } else {
    $result[$block[0]] = $block;
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Например, возможно такое решение:

```
<?php

//Исходные данные из примера
$array = array(
    array(
        'Name 1',
        1,
        0,
        7
    ),
    array(
        'Name 2',
        1,
        0,
        -10
    ),
    array(
        'Name 3',
        0,
        1,
        6
    ),
    array(
        'Name 4',
        0,
        1,
        -11
    ),
    array(
        'Name 1',
        1,
        0,
        10
    ),
    array(
        'Name 3',
        0,
        1,
        7
    ),
);

$result = array();

foreach ($array as $arrayItem) {
    if (!isset($result[$arrayItem[0]])) {
        $result[$arrayItem[0]] = array(
            $arrayItem[0], $arrayItem[1], $arrayItem[2], $arrayItem[3]
        );
    } else {
        $result[$arrayItem[0]][1] += $arrayItem[1];
        $result[$arrayItem[0]][2] += $arrayItem[2];
        $result[$arrayItem[0]][3] += $arrayItem[3];
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);

print_r($result);
```

В результате получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name 2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => -10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name 3
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name 4
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [3] => -11
        )

)
```

Ничего особенного тут придумывать не нужно, просто пробегаем по исходному массиву и добавляем уникальные записи в результирующий. Если есть совпадающие имена, то значения остальных полей добавляем к сохраненным.